# Make a div stop where it should stop, then position fixed

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am using the following to fix a div to almost the top of a page, when the page is scrolled, however, i want to stop it 60px before it reaches the top.

At the moment it goes all the way to the top, then jumps back down 60px which is messy!

```
function moveScroller() {
        var move = function() {
            var st = $(window).scrollTop();
            var ot = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
            var s = $("#scroller");
            if(st > ot) {
                s.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: "60px"
                });
            } else {
                if(st <= ot) {
                    s.css({
                        position: "relative",
                        top: ""
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(move);
        move();
    }

    $(function() {
        moveScroller();
    });
```

Here's a fiddle to see: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6gYg/1/)

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjusted the condition, when you change the element-position to "fixed". For me it works now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function moveScroller() {
        var move = function() {
            var st = $(window).scrollTop();
            var ot = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
            var s = $("#scroller");
            var marginTop = 60;

            if((st+marginTop) > ot) {
                s.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: marginTop + "px"
                });
            } else {
                if(st <= ot) {
                    s.css({
                        position: "relative",
                        top: ""
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(move);
        move();
    }

    $(function() {
        moveScroller();
    });

});
```

Comment: You're welcome :) I would suggest as improvement, that you define the margin-top in the css and on initialization of the function it reads the margin-top of the element, so you separate view-part from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this might accomodate your requirement.

```
function moveScroller() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var ot = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
    var s = $("#scroller");
    if (st > ot) {
        s.css({
            position : "fixed",
            top : "60px"
        });
    } else {
        if (st <= ot) {
            s.css({
                position : "relative",
                top : ""
            });
        }
    }
}


 $(window).scroll(moveScroller);
    $(function() {
       moveScroller();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks but thats almost exactly the same as the fiddle I created, the div gets to the top of the page then jumps down. The question is how to stop it 60px from the top and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Friend sorry I didn't see exactly, but this might solve your purpose :).

```
function moveScroller() {
var st = $(window).scrollTop();
var ot = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
var s = $("#scroller");
if (st >= 200) {

    s.css({
        position : "fixed",
        top : "60px"
    });
} else {
    if (st <= ot) {
        s.css({
            position : "relative",
            top : ""
        });
    }
}
```

}

```
$(window).scroll(moveScroller);
$(function() {
moveScroller();
});
```

Comment: Please test it in the fiddle first, this does not work either, this looks for window scrolling 60px then moves the div.

Comment: Please excuse my brevity... I just tested and posted it, am not doing it blindly, because I know the pain of wrong answer! :). Try this....! As per the requirement specified you can stop the div when the top reaches to 60, but that exact figure 60 can't be attained without flickering as the call back function of window scroll is not called for every pixel, and there is no chance to change the timeinterval of calling of the callback. So flickering occurs hopefully, will let you know when a absolute solution is found

Comment: if there is a chance to make 60 to 0, you can avoid flickering :)